# How to get childs nodes when we don't know their names

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have to work on XML files on which i won't know the names of the nodes. All i know is that the structure will be the same between the different files

The structure will be the above one

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <node2>
        </node2>
    </node2>
</root>
```

I have to make an XSLT file for building an HTML page that will display the content of the nodes.

For now i have this piece of code

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="employe.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID Source</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Adresse</th>
        <th>Code Postal</th>
        <th>Ville</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Poste</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child::*">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

I succeeded in selecting the first and the second level nodes but don't know how to select the third.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing the `match="/"` to `match="/*"` and adding these two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but... could you explain please ?
I'm starting with XLST/XPath and don't really understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: Matching `/*` will match `<root>`. The first template (`*[*]`) matches elements with child elements. The second template (`*[not(*)]`) matches elements without child elements. If it would help, I could attach an entire example.

Comment: No thanks, perfect explanation ! ;)
Just something though, if i change     match="/" to     match="/*" it won't work, cause the table balises aren't created